# How to prevent app restart when changing locale?

Tags: android, locale

I have an app that is not localized and the UI will only be displayed in one language. I would like to avoid having the app restart when the locale of the device is changed.

I am aware that to handle configuration changes myself, I can set the '**locale**' property in configChanges:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|locale"
```

In addition, my app has the following min and target sdk versions:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
```

I suspect that using only 'locale' in android:configChanges only works on devices using an SDK < 17 (details to follow).

I have tested my app with the aforementioned configuration on a device with Android 2.3.5.
The app does not restart (as expected!).

However, on a device with Android 4.2.2 the app restarts even though I have specified locale. To test whether the restart is due to a configuration change, I added the following function:

```
@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()
{
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onRetainNonConfigurationInstance");
    return null;
}
```

In the logcat output I see:

```
10-11 08:53:28.838: D/myapp(10282): onRetainNonConfigurationInstance
```

Since my target API is set to 15, I cannot add "layoutDirection" to my android:configChanges. Is there any other way to prevent my app from restarting on devices using sdk >= 17 ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have targetSdkVersion="15" ? Should be 18... Especially since you plan on supporting Android Jelly Bean 4.2.2

Check [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html).

Comment: The android keyboard implementation changes significantly at targetSdkVersion >= 17. At this point I don't have the time to recode a proper solution for the keyboard, so my targetVersion needs to remain < 17.